# Can I use both session-per-web-request and TransactionScope?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, transactionscope

You know, to implement session-per-web-request in a web application we often create a session in Application_BeginRequest and close it in Application_EndRequest global event handlers. And then every time we access to database, we get the current session by GetCurrentSession instead of open a new session by OpenSession.

So is there any chance to use both session-per-web-request and TransactionScope in a web application? According to NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook (page 117), it says that the call to TransactionScope.Complete should occur after the session has been disposed. Surprisingly it does not say any word about this situation although both session-per-web-request and using TransactionScope are discussed in the same chapter.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
  using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
  {
     // do something here
  }

  scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to use TransactionScope instead of an NHibernate Transaction?

Comment: TransactionScope does not replace NHibernate Transaction, it wraps transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have more than one session/transaction open in each request (probably different databases), which is the only good reason to use a TransactionScope.

If that's the case, just create and Complete() your TransactionScope in Application_BeginRequest/Application_EndRequest, just like you are doing for the Session.

Comment: I don't think every request need TransactionScope, even in this case, I prefer it opens late and closes early as we often do with transaction. We also don't start a transation for every request with session-per-web-request, we just keep an open Session.